# React: how to align icons with text?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am displaying treeview. tree nodes are showing with icons plus and minus. These  icons are showing above the text? how to align node icon and node text in the same line?
please find my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-snow-nfce4i

thanks

Comment: Please include at least the core of the problem as code in the question itself, external links are ok in addition, but shouldn't be the only place we can see the code.

Comment: I tried to put the code with the question. It gving me the issues in posting the code. Sandbox is the running example and its showing exactly the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `::marker` with `::before`, remove `list-style-type` and adjust padding from `ul`.
`::marker` can not be modified with as many properties as pseudo-elements, therefore in order to style it you need to switch to a pseudo-element.

```js
//ProductsTreeView.js  - line 177
const StyledLI = styled.li`
  list-style-type: none;
  ::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    ${({ expanded }) =>
      `background: url(${expanded ? minus : plus})};`};
  }
`;
```

```js
//ProductsTreeView.js  - line 294
<ul style={{paddingLeft: '1.8rem'}}>
```

### Update for Paper Icons

First initialize an Icon property on Node class:

```js
//ProductsTreeView.js - line 209
class Node {
  description = "n/a";
  id = -1;
  key_id = -1;
  linkpagename = "";
  icon = "";
  isActive = false;
  nodes = [];

  constructor(description, id, key_id, icon, linkpagename) {
    this.description = description;
    this.id = id;
    this.key_id = key_id;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.linkpagename = linkpagename;
  }

// the rest of the code...
```

Then assign a value to Icon property from your XML's "imageOpen" field:

```js
//ProductsTreeView.js - line 236
const icon =
  entity.children[
    entity.children.findIndex((child) => child.name === "imageOpen")
  ].value;

//ProductsTreeView.js - line 250
const node = new Node(descriptionText, id, key_id, icon, linkPageName);
```

Then on your StyledLI assign this Icon prop as "isPaper":

```js
//ProductsTreeView.js - line 387
<StyledLI
  id={node.id}
  expanded={node.isActive}
  isPaper={node.icon}
  isLeaf={!node.nodes.length}
  to={node.linkpagename}
  key={node.key_id}
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    onToggle(node);
  }}
>
```

Then readjust your CSS-in-JS:

```js
//ProductTreeView.js - line 177
const StyledLI = styled.li`
  list-style-type: none;
  ::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    ${({ expanded, isPaper }) => `background: url(${isPaper === "paper.gif" ? paper : (expanded ? minus : plus)})};`};
  }
`;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks George. I tried your solution and it works. Please find my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-snow-nfce4i              Also, how to display paper image all the time to the third level nodes(whether its expanded or not expanded assuming first node is at zero level.

Comment: @TestUser please see my updated answer. Also, please mark it as completed if it worked.

Comment: Thanks George for all the help. It works great. Please let me know how to mark it as complete and is there any way I can put more stars/high rating. Also, I have another question realted to CORS. I will create another post for that.

Comment: Also, is there a way to showing loading... when its taking time to load the data in the TreeView. In real time, data is coming from api and its returning large amount of data.

Comment: @TestUser To mark the question as answered, you click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: @TestUser You are using classes so you need to do that in your constructor's state. It's been a while since I coded in OOP for React, so I would suggest you to check the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 1):

I tried modifying your StyledLi component and working with ::marker exclusively, to no avail. However, I managed to align them as such:

```
   const StyledLI = styled.li`
      list-style-type: none;
    `;
```

And in the TreeNode:

```
class TreeNode extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { node, onToggle } = this.props;

    const activeChildren =
      node.isActive && node.nodes.length ? (
        <ul>
          {node.nodes.map((node) => (
            <TreeNode
              id={node.id}
              key={node.key_id}
              node={node}
              onToggle={onToggle}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : null;

    return (
      <StyledLI
        id={node.id}
        expanded={node.isActive}
        isLeaf={!node.nodes.length}
        to={node.linkpagename}
        key={node.key_id}
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.stopPropagation();
          onToggle(node);
        }}
      >
        <div style={{
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
          <img src={node.isActive ? minus : plus} />

          <Link
            to={node.linkpagename}
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#000000" }}
          >
            {node.description}
          </Link>{" "}
          - {node.key_id} - {node.linkpagename}
        </div>

        {activeChildren}
      </StyledLI>
    );
  }
}
```

You can copy-paste this into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before` pseudo-element instead of markers. This is more flexible way.

```
// css
.list {
  list-style: none;
}

.item {
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 20px;
}

.item::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: url(https://uploads.codesandbox.io/uploads/user/25a43e4c-a00e-4028-8cde-b4bc9a9987f9/pkCB-plus.gif);
}

// render
<ul className="list">
  <li className="item">Some text 1</li>
  <li className="item">Some text 2</li>
  <li className="item">Some text 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, please check my sandbox, i am displaying plus minus icons. icons are not aligning with text. please help how to fix my code